# How to apply a loop when inserting a record?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api2

I am building a form to register `assets` in a database, the assets are repeated many times for that reason I created an input where I store the number of assets so that the user can enter n number of assets.

I am applying a for loop but it only executes once, why?

```cs
public async Task<ActionResult> Crear([FromBody] DtoEscrituraActivo dto_activo)
{
    Activo activo = mapper.Map<Activo>(dto_activo);
    for (int x = 0; x < dto_activo.cantidad; x++)
    {
        context.Add(activo);
        await context.SaveChangesAsync();
        ActivoTipoCategorium activoTipoCategorium = context.ActivoTipoCategoria.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == activo.IdActivoTipoCategoria);
        int? Compania = activo.IdDepartamento;
        int? Departamento = activo.IdDepartamento;
        int? Unidad = activo.IdUnidad;
        int? Localidad = activo.IdLocalidad;
        int? ActivoTipo = activoTipoCategorium.IdActivoTipo;
        int? Categoria = activo.IdActivoTipoCategoria;
        int? Activo = activo.Id;

        string CodigoDeBarra = string.Concat(Compania, Departamento, Unidad, Localidad, ActivoTipo, Categoria, Activo);
        activo.IdCodigo = Int64.Parse(CodigoDeBarra);
        await context.SaveChangesAsync();
    }
    DtoLecturaActivo dtoActivo = mapper.Map<DtoLecturaActivo>(activo);
    return new CreatedAtRouteResult("BuscarPorID", new { Id = dtoActivo.Id }, dtoActivo);
}
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: are you sure that dto_activo.cantidad is not being changed in the loop?

Comment: Firstly, you don't need us to tell you what you can determine for yourself by debugging. You should not be posting a question here without debugging first anyway. If you don't know how to debug then stop what you're doing and learn. Even if you can't solve the problem, you can explain to use what you see when you debug.

Comment: Secondly, why would you be calling `SaveChanges` inside the loop at all, never mind twice for each iteration? Make all the changes first, then save them all at the end in a single batch.

Comment: @Hogan sorry, post updated

Comment: @jmcilhinney post updated.
I am calling it twice because the first time I save the record in the database, when it is registered I get its id, then I need to generate a barcode (`CodigoDeBarra`) this is generated with the union of several fields including the ID of the `asset` = `Activo`
And I save the changes

Comment: If you need to call `SaveChanges` twice in order to use auto-generated data, you should still be doing so outside the loop. Create all the data first, then call `SaveChanges` once, then loop over the data and use the IDs to generate the barcodes, then call `SaveChanges` again. Basically, save data in a batch rather than once for every record. If you need to use data from the first save, save two batches.

Answer (score 2):

You are running the loop 10 times.

You have this statement here

```
for (int i = 0; i < dto_activo.cantidad; i++)
```

Which says (in english) run the loop 10 times with the variable i having the value 1 thru 10.  (Why are you using the name "i"?  i is a terrible name -- as is evidenced by your problem.)

However, when we look at the content of the loop -- what you are doing does not change based on i.  You do the same thing 10 times with no change -- So only one record gets changed.

You need to do new record insert in the loop to create new records or change what you are editing (like an id) -- so I would expect to see something like this:

```
string CodigoDeBarra = string.Concat(Compania, Departamento, Unidad + i, Localidad, ActivoTipo, Categoria, Activo);
```

See how I'm using i here to do something different on every loop (changing a different un id in this case.)

BUT you never use i anywhere outside of the loop control -- so I know you are not changing different records.

Comment: post updated.  I am calling it twice because the first time I save the record in the database, when it is registered I get its id, then I need to generate a barcode (CodigoDeBarra) this is generated with the union of several fields including the ID of the asset = Activo And I save the changes

Comment: So do you mean you can get the id only after `context.Add(activo)`?If so,you can do  what `jmcilhinney` said,so that you only need to use savechanges twice.